# Why isn't this jquery triggering immediately

Tags: jquery, triggers, window, width

Basically I have this jquery set up and the first part if statement works. But for the one with the tooltip it doesn't quite go to plan.

Here's the code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
            if (!$('#largeS').length) {
                $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="largeS" href="http://imgstr.thefinishedbox.com/css/large.css" />');
                if ($.browser.msie && (jQuery.browser.version > 6.9999) && (jQuery.browser.version < 7.9999) ) { //IE7
                    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="ie7Large" href="http://imgstr.thefinishedbox.com/css/ie7Large.css" />');
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#largeS').remove();
            if ($.browser.msie && (jQuery.browser.version > 6.9999) && (jQuery.browser.version < 7.9999) ) { //IE7
                $('#ie7Large').remove();
            }
        }
        if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
            if(!$('#sidebar .tip').hasClass('vertical')) {
                $('#sidebar .tip').addClass('vertical');
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#sidebar .tip').removeClass('vertical');
        }
    }).trigger('resize');
```

The sidebar tip doesn't trigger upon browser load so the vertical class isn't getting added even though it's bigger than 1024 window width. But it works upon changing the window size after loading.

Not sure why, any help?

edit: Here's the live version: http://tfbox.com - tooltips are on popular posts.

Comment: why not just move that anon function to a named function and call it onload?

Comment: Just a blind guess, but I don't think the window has a `resize` event on the `onLoad` event. If you want it to execute `onLoad` place that portion into either `$(document).ready();` or `$(window).load()` event.

Comment: I would imagine that the code doesn't run immediately because it's not being called until the window is re-sized. Changing $(window).resize... to $(document).ready ($(window).load may be more appropriate in this scenario) should give you the desired results.

Comment: Once on ready() and subsequently on every resize()?..  btw.. What wordpress theme is that? :)

Comment: I don't understand why the window resize works upon page loading & changing the width once loaded.. BUT the tooltips only change upon the window resizing after load.

Comment: @conqenator it's a theme I made lol.

Comment: @mkoryak what do you mean? My jquery knoledge isn't that amazing lol I know the basics.

Comment: @Daryl: Forgive me, I know this is off the topic, but can you tell me what theme this was derived from or where I can get this one?  Loved it. :)

Comment: @conqenator It's not a free theme lol, I custom built it. I do take that as a compliment though.

Comment: @Daryl: If I'm interested in buying it?

Comment: @conqenator its a personal project that im building. It's not for sale sorry. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
        width = parseInt(width);
        if (width > 1024) {
            $('#sidebar .tip').addClass('vertical');
        } else {
           $('#sidebar .tip').removeClass('vertical');
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
        $(window).resize(function() {
            adjustStyle($(this).width());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you try this:

```
function resizeWindow() {
        if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
            if (!$('#largeS').length) {
                $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="largeS" href="http://imgstr.thefinishedbox.com/css/large.css" />');
                if ($.browser.msie && (jQuery.browser.version > 6.9999) && (jQuery.browser.version < 7.9999) ) { //IE7
                    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="ie7Large" href="http://imgstr.thefinishedbox.com/css/ie7Large.css" />');
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#largeS').remove();
            if ($.browser.msie && (jQuery.browser.version > 6.9999) && (jQuery.browser.version < 7.9999) ) { //IE7
                $('#ie7Large').remove();
            }
        }
        if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
            if(!$('#sidebar .tip').hasClass('vertical')) {
                $('#sidebar .tip').addClass('vertical');
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#sidebar .tip').removeClass('vertical');
        }
    }

$(function() {
   resizeWindow();
   $(window).resize(resizeWindow);
}
```